# Why am I getting an error while creating index command in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, syntax

Here is the table on which I am trying to create index

```
create table domestic(
id SERIAL primary key NOT NULL,
Dto int DEFAULT NULL,
Dfrom int DEFAULT NULL,
courierType varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
weight varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

this table has been created and I am trying to add indexes to Dto and Dfrom using following command.

```
create index to on domestic(Dto);
create index from on domestic(Dfrom);
```

I get these errors:

```
user=# create table domestic(
user(# id SERIAL primary key NOT NULL,
user(# Dto int DEFAULT NULL,
user(# Dfrom int DEFAULT NULL,
user(# courierType varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
user(# weight varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
user(# );
CREATE TABLE
user=# create index to on domestic(Dto);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to"
LINE 1: create index to on domestic(Dto);
                     ^
user=# create index from on domestic(Dfrom);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 1: create index from on domestic(Dfrom);
```

I did try putting to and from in single quotes and it is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

> I did try putting to and from in single quotes and it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Single quotes are for [***values***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS): `'value'`.
For [***identifiers***](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) you would have to use double quotes: `"identifier"`.

But it's always best to use legal names that do not need double-quoting to begin with. Avoid [reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like <strike>`to`</strike> or <strike>`from`</strike> as identifiers in SQL.

Related:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Answer (score 3):

You have named your index using reserved words, replace `to` and `from` and it will work.

> ```
> create table domestic(
> id SERIAL primary key NOT NULL,
> Dto int DEFAULT NULL,
> Dfrom int DEFAULT NULL,
> courierType varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
> weight varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> create index to on domestic(Dto);
> create index from on domestic(Dfrom);
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to"
> LINE 1: create index to on domestic(Dto);
>                      ^
> ```

> ```
> create index ix_to on domestic(Dto);
> create index ix_from on domestic(Dfrom);
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d7118ede52ff5c2f1755123dd0de6aee)*